# Breaking a while loop with more than one character in c programming

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar

How do i get this snippet of code to break the while loop with both "a" and "A"?
I can't get the OR function right. Thanks in advance for the help.

`while((product = getchar()) !='a')`

Comment: "*cant get the OR function right*". It should be AND not OR. In any case, please show us that attempted expression that you "can't get right".

Comment: Note, use `int product;` and not `char product;` to distinguish the typical 257 different values from `int getchar(void)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to break the loop when `product` is `a` or `A`, you need to check if `product` is not `a` *and* not `A` in your loop condition:

```
while((product = getchar()) !='a' && product != 'A')
```